# Lay or Lie in "what powers lies between their hands"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

This is for sure a duplicate question, but I'm sorry I'm just getting confused no matter how many articles I read. In the sentence,

> And still they are not aware what powers lies between their hands!

Should this be lays, lies? And what should it be if the tense were changed to "were not aware"?

Comment: It should be *lie*. Not *lies*, not *lays*.

Comment: Or *power* instead of *powers*

Answer (score 5):

And still they **are** not aware what powers **lie** between their hands!

And still they **were** not aware what powers **lay** between their hands!

> B1 [ I + adv/prep, L ]
>
> present participle lying
>   past tense lay
>   past participle lain
>
> If something lies in a particular place, position, or direction, it is
>   in that place, position, or direction

[Lie (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lie)
[Lie (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lie)
[English verb: to lie](https://www.writingenglish.com/cverbs/lie.htm)

Present tense:
Singular: I lie, you lie, he/she/it lies.
Plural: we lie, you lie, they lie.

Past tense:
Singular: I lay, you lay, he/she/it lay.
Plural: we lay, you lay, they lay.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers but, just to confuse you further, there's another possibility.

> And still they are not aware what power **lies** between their hands!

This means that they have power between their hands but they are not aware of it.

> And still they are not aware what power **lays** between their hands!

This means that 'power' is treated as an agent and it places something unspecified into their hands, i.e.

"And still they are not aware of the thing that power lays between their hands!"

So my answer is that *both* are possible but they mean different things.

Comment: To make the latter more clear: *...what [thing] power lays between...*.

Comment: Drew: no. Lays is the present tense of the transitive verb "to lay".